# How to get region name from latitude and Longitude (Xamarin.Form c#)?

Tags: c#, android, xaml, button, xamarin.forms

```
            `var locator = CrossGeolocator.Current;
            locator.DesiredAccuracy = 50;
            ActInd.IsRunning = true;
            Submit.IsEnabled = false;
            var position = await 
            locator.GetPositionAsync(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(20), null, true);

            var geoposition = new Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Position(position.Latitude,position.Longitude);
            var possibleAddresses = await geoCoder.GetAddressesForPositionAsync(geoposition);

            string finaladdress = "";
            foreach (var address in possibleAddresses)

                finaladdress = address.ElementAt(0).getlocality(); //Notrecognising getlocality();
```

`
Not able to implement the getlocality function to get city or region name

Comment: I would check for case-sensitivity; I believe that should be `getLocality`

Comment: GetAddressesForPositionAsync returns a list of strings, there is no region data included

Comment: Alright, but is there another way to get city or region based on latitude and longitude?

Comment: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/GeolocatorPlugin